# Why isn't by lazy applied in fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know there is a `lateinit` or `lazy` keyword in Kotlin to prevent indiscriminate initialization and thus minimize wasted resources.

I wanted to use the lazy keyword to use `findViewById` when necessary events occur.

However, if I use the lazy keyword, nothing happens. It doesn't even cause an error.

Conversely, when `findViewId` is normally used in `onCreateView`, click event occurs normally.

Why doesn't lazy work?

```
class BodyPartDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener{
    private val ll: LinearLayout? by lazy { view?.findViewById(R.id.ll_body_part) }
//    private lateinit var button: Button
    private val button: Button? by lazy { view?.findViewById(R.id.start) }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part_dialog, container, false)
//        ll = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_body_part)
//        button = view.findViewById(R.id.start)
        ll?.apply { clipToOutline = true }

        button?.setOnClickListener { // Nothing Happened
            Toast.makeText(context, "Noting Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        return view
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getView()` that is behind the `view` property returns whatever you returned from `onCreateView()`. When you access `view` inside `onCreateView()`, it hasn't yet returned anything and hence a `null` is returned, and your `?.` safecall becomes a no-op.

You can use a `lazy` approach like this after `onCreateView()`, such as in `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: Oh no way, does `view` of `view?.findViewById(R.id.ll_body_part)` mean `getView()`?

Not the `local variable view` in `onCreteView()`?

Comment: Yes, the `view` in `onCreateView()` is not in scope in the `lazy` block.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I almost understood. thank you.

This seems to have happened because Kotlin is still unfamiliar with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be initializing things in the wrong order.

Consider that renaming a local variable always preserves semantics, so let's modify your code a little:

```
private val ll: LinearLayout? by lazy { view?.findViewById(R.id.ll_body_part) }
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val someRandomView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part_dialog, container, false)
    ll?.apply { clipToOutline = true }

    button?.setOnClickListener { // Nothing Happened
        Toast.makeText(context, "Noting Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    return someRandomView
}
```

Do you see the issue?  `ll` is being initialized with a `view` that hasn't been assigned yet in `onCreateView`.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand exactly.

When `ll` is used, isn't it after `view` is initialized?

So, isn't `findViewById` also available?

Answer (score 0):

`view` (or really `getView()`) is the view that is returned from `onCreateView()`. You're trying to access that before you have returned from `onCreateView()` so it returns null, and your lazy value is then also null. You can make this work by accessing it later, ie. in `onViewCreated()`

```
class BodyPartDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), View.OnClickListener{
    private val ll: LinearLayout? by lazy { view?.findViewById(R.id.ll_body_part) }
//    private lateinit var button: Button
    private val button: Button? by lazy { view?.findViewById(R.id.start) }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part_dialog, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ll?.apply { clipToOutline = true }
        button?.setOnClickListener { // Nothing Happened
            Toast.makeText(context, "Noting Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

This is more clear if you use `requireView()` since it returns a non-null `View` and rather throws an exception, so your app would have crashed with the error message `did not return a View from onCreateView() or this was called before onCreateView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get access to View in the future using 'by lazy'

```
private val previewImage by lazy { requireActivity().findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivImage) }
```

Then you can use it like

```
previewImage.setImageURI(imageUri)
```